# Purged comments reappear when posting a comment after purging

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, user-interface, moderator-tools

When purging all comments under a post, the comments then reappear immediately after if I click to add a comment. They then disappear again after posting the comment.

It's not uncommon to leave a comment when purging a thread, as often the comment thread has gotten out of hand and a mod explanation of why the thread is deleted is helpful.

> [image]

### Comments disappear after purging.

> [image]

### Comments reappear when posting a comment.

> [image]

### They then disappear again after posting the comment.

> [image]

Comment: Bear with me, there may be a few bug reports. It's a bit of hack and slashing in the mod queue at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a userscript bug? E.g. if you have a script to see deleted comments more easily.

Comment: @Randal'Thor no, not at all. I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Is the the AJAX show/hide magic, or does the behavior survive a reload of the page? There's some other strangeness with deleting and posting comments that goes away on a hard reload.

Comment: @rob good question. I'd say it disappears on reload. I need to also test it without userscripts. I always forget those things darn it. I'll have to come back to this. I'm a tad busy.  Sorry

Comment: Should we blame caching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a user-script bug.

The "Purge all" button and the way it updates the UI is different from how the moderator menu does it.

When the moderator menu purges comments, it follows it with a call to `StackExchange.moderator.loadAllComments($post)` which is mostly just a wrapper around `StackExchange.comments.loadAll($post, '?includeDeleted=true')`.  This displays all comments on the post in their new deleted state.

The user-script is likely just hiding the comments `display:none` and the script that shows the add form is interacting with that in an unexpected way.  If the script truly wants to remove those from the UI, the best way would be to call `StackExchange.comments.loadAll($post)` after purging the comments.